# Android. Узнать объём кэша выделенный приложению

Tags: android

Всем привет! Кто знает как узнать объём кэша который выделен приложению программно??? 
Я тут в google откапал вот эту строчку Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()не эта ли случайно??? Просто я не знаю, это узнаётся максимальный кэш приложения или максимальный кэш в android.

Answer (score 1):

Вы про кэш в памяти говорите или на диске? Если в памяти, то Вам, возможно, поможет статья http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html и LruCache, который в ней упоминают